# What are EL2HLT, EL3HLT, EL3RST?

Tags: kernel, history

There was a thread [about ENOANO](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/167368/what-is-enoano-no-anode-intended-to-be-used-for), explaining an obscure errno macro that still lingers around.

I would like to similarly ask about these errno values: what the *hell* were they for?

- EL2HLT "Level 2 halted"
- EL2NSYNC "Level 2 not synchronized"
- EL3HLT "Level 3 halted"
- EL3RST "Level 3 reset"

Although I mostly managed to decipher all other mysterious errno values (apparently some come from RFS, others come from STREAMS), literally the only clue I found about these four is that on Linux, `<include/asm-sparc/solerrno.h>` makes references to "run levels", so they could be related to the Solaris init system from some alternate timeline.

Comment: One of the z/OS development manuals mentions EL2HLT. Is it s390x related ?

Answer (score 1):

I observed EL2NSYNC and EL2HLT with a GSM modem connected via serial port and n_gsm / 07.10 GSM multiplexing protocol. The GSM multiplexing creates a bunch of virtual serial ports (/dev/gsmttyXX) which are multiplexed over a single physical serial port. In case of synchronization problems or other protocol errors on the underlying multiplexing protocol

```
open()
```

fails with EL2NSYNC or EL2HLT.

Answer (score 0):

In this [discussion](https://lkml.org/lkml/2018/1/3/535) EL2HLT is the error code if connecting to something which requires (i think) another process running or a kernel level thread being extant (?.)

If the process is unexistant or something else missing this error code tells the program what something fundamental is missing.

This could include opening and reading a file on a SAN provided storage media but the interface (FC or Ethernet) is down.